# gvNix free for building Commercial Solutions?

Tags: spring-roo

The main goal is to install gvNix for adding support for services in Spring Roo. According to the documentation, it's possible to install it via addon. Is it a good solution for adding services support for Spring Roo? Is it free to use for building a commercial solution (we're not planning on changing gvNix code, just use it to generate code, as Spring Roo does)?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of gvNIX project is to build a Java framework to develop enterprise applications, not limited to services only: reports, UI standards, integration with legacy applications and so on.

[gvNIX](http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/DocGvnix) is a good solution for those apps features not covered by Roo.

Currently gvNIX is licensed under GPLv3.

Both Roo and gvNIX are development environments, they generate web applications that embed Spring Framework, so the license you should see is Spring Framework license, which won't have any problem.

Anyway, yes, it is free for building commercial solutions. Try gvNIX 1.2.1 and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Nevertheless, your instructions (https://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/InstallGvnix) for installing gvNIX don't work. I keep getting the following: web roo> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.gvnix.cit.security.roo.addon
Could not find specified bundle with symbolic name: org.gvnix.cit.security.roo.addon

Comment: I think this is a problem with RooBot?

Comment: If i try your instructions again, using the URL, i get the following: web roo> osgi start --url http://gvnix.googlecode.com/svn/repo/org/gvnix/org.gvnix.web.screen.roo.addon/1.2.1-RELEASE/org.gvnix.web.screen.roo.addon-1.2.1-RELEASE.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.gvnix.web.screen.roo.addon [83]: Unable to resolve 83.0: missing requirement [83.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.gvnix.web.i18n.roo.addon)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))

Comment: Yes, we're working on improve doc, whereas use gvNIX 1.2.1, it includes Roo 1.2.4 and all gvNIX addons